# removing objects from List<Map<String,Object>> in Java

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a List of items such as apple, banana. 
I have another List of items that is a Map type with apple, banana, grape. 
how can i delete all values from 2nd list of items that overlap with the first?

Comment: Which programming language? What have you tried?

Comment: java. I've tried .clear() and it just returns me of 'null' for deleted value. I want to delete and resize the map

Comment: In your Map, the String key refers to what ? and what's contained in the object ?

Comment: Can you provide *code* illustrating a use case, and/or what you've tried doing to solve this? Maybe another sample input/output or two? Because it's not at all clear to me that the title of this question has anything to do with the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `remove(K key)` method on each duplicate item instead of the `clear()` method. Also, make sure your map doesn't allow for null values, if you actually want to use the returned object as an indication of the existence of your recently deleted item.

> If this map permits null values, then a return value of null does not necessarily indicate that the map contained no mapping for the key; it's also possible that the map explicitly mapped the key to null.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove-java.lang.Object-